# Selecting data where a field contains a possible value

Tags: php, mysql

I've been looking for answers to this for a couple days now, but I must be looking in the wrong places:

What I'm trying to do is create an OnCall rotation page that will cycle through entries in a database based on a set of weeks associated to them. The code I have calling this data is as shown:

```
//Collect data
date_default_timezone_set('America/Boise');
$weekNumber = date("W");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM oncall.info WHERE Weeks LIKE '$weekNumber'";
$sql_con = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$data = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_con);
```

And the entries in the database look something like:

```
Name    | Weeks
Joe       1, 4, 7, 10
Sally     2, 5, 8, 11
Quigon    3, 6, 9, 12
```

So, being new to this kind of thing, I'm not sure if I'm taking the wrong approach with the php or if my data isn't stored appropriately in the database.

Any ideas, thoughts, or suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Your data is stored inapropriate in the DB! Never store multiple values in one column.

Comment: Don't ever store comma-separated values in your DB. This is a wrong design and you need to change it **now**. Have each Name repeated several times in the table, each connected to one Week number.

Comment: @juergen "Never store multiple values in one column" - you sure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Name    | Weeks
Joe       1
Joe       4
Joe       7
Joe       10
Sally     2
Sally     5
Sally     8
Sally     11
Quigon    3
Quigon    6
Quigon    9
Quigon    12
```

Then you can be like

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM oncall.info WHERE Weeks = '$weekNumber'";
```

Your table should also have a primary key, it will help you manage your table better as well.